# Fazer um Select dentro de uma dropdown com ajuda de jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

Não consigo fazer o script para que isto funcione. Tenho que fazer pesquisa para dentro da segunda Dropdown (Vigararias) e guardar o ID da segunda dropdown para fazer o Post o ID na BD

Controller:
Este Controlador vai buscar as dioceses da primeira dropdown.

```
public ActionResult GetDioceses()
        {
            //  Obter todas as dioceses usando Entity Framework e LINQ 
            var dioceses = db.Diocese
                .Select(d => new { d.DioceseID, d.Nome })
                .OrderBy(d => d.Nome);
            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())          
                return Json(new SelectList(
                           dioceses,
                           "DioceseID",
                           "Nome"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                           );     
            return View(dioceses);
        }
```

Este controlador vai buscar todas as vigararias pertencentes a diocese.

```
public ActionResult GetVigarariasByDioceses(int DioceseId)
        {
            // Obter Vigararias de uma Diocese utilizando LINQ.
            var vigararias = db.Vigararia
                .Where(v => v.DioceseID == DioceseId)
                .Select(v => new { v.VigarariaID, v.Nome })
                .OrderBy(v => v.Nome);

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new SelectList(
                                vigararias,
                                "VigarariaID",
                                "Nome"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );

            return View(vigararias);
        }
```

View:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetDioceses", "Paroquia")"
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, diocese) {
                    items += "<option value='" + diocese.Value + "'>" + diocese.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Dioceses").html(items);
            });

            $("#Dioceses").change(function () {
                 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetVigarariasByDioceses", "Paroquia")/"+ $("#Dioceses > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                    var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, vigararia) {
                        items += "<option value='" + vigararia.Value + "'>" + vigararia.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#Vigararias").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
 <div class="form-group">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Dioceses", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select id="Dioceses" name="Dioceses" class="form-control"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Vigararias", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })                              
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <select id="Vigararias" name="Vigararias" class="form-control"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é o que passar para `$.getJSON()`?

Comment: Sim é essa a minha dúvida.

Comment: Já fiz alterações no script

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente está tudo ok. Use `@Url.Action` para montar os endereços do jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetDioceses", "MeuController")", function (data) { ... }

$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetVigariasByDioceses", "MeuController")/" + $("#Dioceses > option:selected").val(), function (data) { ... }
```

---

**EDIT**

Se `$.getJSON()` não funcionar, use [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) ou [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Mostra os itens da primeira dropdown para não da segunda.

Comment: Chegou a colocar breakpoints no *Controller*? Revisou o código HTML gerado?

Comment: No controller ele não chega a entrar do método "GetVigarariasByDioceses", já revi a view e não consigo identificar o erro.

Comment: O nome do script estava mal mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: *O nome do método estava mal não do script.

Comment: Você marcou algum dos métodos com `[HttpPost]`? O certo é `[HttpGet]`. A grafia dos elementos está correta?

Comment: Grafia dos elementos? qual o significado .sorry

Comment: Se os nomes das *Actions* estão escritos corretamente.

Comment: Sim está tudo correto. o problema penso que está aqui.  '$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetVigarariasByDioceses", "Paroquia")/" + $("#Dioceses > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {...}', porque nunca chega a entrar no método "GetVigarariasByDioceses"

Comment: Será que vou precisar de AJAX?

Comment: Editei a resposta com sugestões.

Comment: Com o get continua só a funcionar a primeira dropdown. Se eu reformular para apenas uma função dará? é que ele nunca chega a ir a segunda função.

Comment: Deve ser algum outro problema. O código aparentemente está ok.

Comment: Desisti e reformulei o código, mas tenho outro problema.http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108464/problema-a-fazer-a-query-dentro-da-segunda-dropdown