# Problema a fazer a query dentro da segunda Dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, linq

Entra sempre no erro do ajax:

```
error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve vigararias.' + ex);
                }
```

Erro na tela:

> Failed to retrieve vigararias.[object Object]

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#Dioceses").change(function () {
            $("#Vigararias").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetVigarariasByDioceses", "Paroquia")', // chamar o metodo em json
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#Dioceses").val() },
                success: function (vigararias) {
                    $.each(vigararias, function (i, vigararia) {
                        $("#Vigararias").append('<option value="' + vigararia.Value + '">' + vigararia.Text + '</option>');
                    }); 
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve vigararias.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Dioceses", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                               @Html.DropDownList("Dioceses", (SelectList)ViewBag.dioceses, "--Escolha uma diocese--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Vigararias", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Vigararias", new SelectList(string.Empty, "VigarariaID", "Nome"), "--Escolha uma Vigararia--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult CriarParoquia()
        {
            ViewBag.Dioceses = new SelectList(db.Diocese, "DioceseID", "Nome");   
            return View();
        }

public JsonResult GetVigarariasByDioceses(int DioceseId)
        {
            // Obter Vigararias de uma Diocese utilizando LINQ.
            var vigararias = db.Vigararia
                .Where(v => v.DioceseID == DioceseId)
                .Select(v => new { v.VigarariaID, v.Nome })
                .OrderBy(v => v.Nome);

            return Json(new SelectList(vigararias,"VigarariaID","Nome"));
        }
```

Comment: Essa *Action* `GetVigarariasByDioceses` não está marcada com `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: Não estava, mas mesmo assim dá o mesmo erro."Failed to retrieve vigararias.[object Object]".

Comment: Chega a entrar na *Action*?

Comment: Não, fiz breakpoint e não entra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto aqui não vai funcionar:

```
    public JsonResult GetVigarariasByDioceses(int DioceseId)
    {
        // Obter Vigararias de uma Diocese utilizando LINQ.
        var vigararias = db.Vigararia
            .Where(v => v.DioceseID == DioceseId)
            .Select(v => new { v.VigarariaID, v.Nome })
            .OrderBy(v => v.Nome);

        return Json(new SelectList(vigararias,"VigarariaID","Nome"));
    }
```

Mais especificamente esta parte:

```
return Json(new SelectList(vigararias,"VigarariaID","Nome"));
```

Não se passa um `SelectList` por JSON porque o código JS não entende a estruturação de `SelectList`. O correto seria:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetVigarariasByDioceses(int id)
    {
        // Obter Vigararias de uma Diocese utilizando LINQ.
        var vigararias = db.Vigararia
            .Where(v => v.DioceseID == DioceseId)
            .Select(v => new { v.VigarariaID, v.Nome })
            .OrderBy(v => v.Nome);

        return Json(vigararias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Note que `id`:

```
data: { id: $("#Dioceses").val() },
```

Precisa ser igual ao argumento da *Action*:

```
public JsonResult GetVigarariasByDioceses(int id)
```

Aqui, naturalmente, precisa ter os nomes que você definiu em *Controller*:

```
$.each(vigararias, function (i, vigararia) {
    $("#Vigararias").append('<option value="' + vigararia.VigarariaID + '">' + vigararia.Nome + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Mesmo assim não entra no método.

Comment: Esqueci um detalhe. Veja agora.

Comment: Finalmente, agora só tem um problema na Dropdown, não vai buscar o nome das vigararias, aparece "undefined".

Comment: @user10271 Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado por tudo.